# How to allow user to control current audio duration from LockScreen or ControlCenter in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I allow user to play audio tracks inside my app.I have already set controls but I have problems of setting slider of current audio playback on the lock screen.Here is the screenshot of it :[image]

How to set current song playback and allow user to change it using song slider on the lock screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you gone through MPRemoteCommandCenter methods and properties, I believe you can use the commands here to skip forward or backword.
I am afraid you won't get a smooth slider similar to iTunes music as they have not exposed anything like that for developers.

And for setting track duration on lock screen you have to set MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration like below::

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *center = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
            NSDictionary *songInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [NSNumber numberWithDouble:songDuration],MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration,
                                      nil];


            [center setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];
```

Comment: but i saw some apps from different developers that allow user to slide track on the lock screen

Comment: I am not using it personally and I haven't found anything yet in the public APIs suitable for a smooth slider. Not sure about the private APIs though.